# Removing the shipping price, if the amount has reached a certain value

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a working shopping cart page, but I do not know how to remove the shipping value, once a user has reached a total, for example, of 50 or higher. In the previous version this was already implemented, so I tried to compare and figure out how to implement this in the new page, but am not skilled enough in JavaScript. This is the JavaScript I am using right now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var taxRate = 0.05;
var shippingRate = 5.00; 
var fadeTime = 300;

$('.product-quantity input').change( function() {
  updateQuantity(this);
});

$('.product-removal button').click( function() {
  removeItem(this);
});

function recalculateCart()
{
  var subtotal = 0;

  $('.product').each(function () {
    subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.product-line-price').text());
  });

  var tax = subtotal * taxRate;
  var shipping = (subtotal > 0 ? shippingRate : 0);
  var total = subtotal + tax + shipping;

  $('.totals-value').fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
    $('#cart-subtotal').html(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-tax').html(tax.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-shipping').html(shipping.toFixed(2));
    $('#cart-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
    if(total == 0){
      $('.checkout').fadeOut(fadeTime);
    }else{
      $('.checkout').fadeIn(fadeTime);
    }
    $('.totals-value').fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });
}


function updateQuantity(quantityInput)
{
  var productRow = $(quantityInput).parent().parent();
  var price = parseFloat(productRow.children('.product-price').text());
  var quantity = $(quantityInput).val();
  var linePrice = price * quantity;

  productRow.children('.product-line-price').each(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
      $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
      recalculateCart();
      $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
    });
  });  
}


function removeItem(removeButton)
{
  var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
  productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
    productRow.remove();
    recalculateCart();
  });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set shipping to zero when `subtotal + tax >= 50` (assuming that's the business rule).

```
var shipping = subtotal > 0 && (subtotal + tax < 50) ? shippingRate : 0;
```

And then, for display purposes, set the shipping value element to empty when `shipping === 0`. A ternary operator is one way to do it.

```
$('#cart-shipping').html(shipping === 0 ? '' : shipping.toFixed(2));
```